# Why do we use the possessive in "doctor's appointment"?

Tags: phrase-usage, possessives

Doctors seem to be unique among professions in that we use the possessive when referring to their appointments. "Doctor's appointment" is many times more common than "doctor appointment" [according to ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doctor+appointment%2Cdoctor%27s+appointment). However, for every kind of specialty it seems to be the reverse:

- [Optometrist appointment is preferred over optometrist's appointment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optometrist+appointment%2Coptometrist%27s+appointment)
- [Eye doctor appointment is preferred over eye doctor's appointment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eye+doctor+appointment%2Ceye+doctor%27s+appointment)
- [Dentist appointment is preferred to dentist's appointment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dentist+appointment%2Cdentist%27s+appointment)
- [Orthodontist appointment is preferred over orthodontist's appointment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=orthodontist+appointment%2Corthodontist%27s+appointment)
- [Oncologist appointment is preferred over oncologist's appointment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oncologist+appointment%2Concologist%27s+appointment)
- [Psychiatrist appointment is preferred over psychiatrist's appointment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=psychiatrist+appointment%2Cpsychiatrist%27s+appointment)

What makes "doctor" different? Is this actually specific to that word, or are there other cases I haven't considered where we would use a possessive form?

Comment: Hm. Intriguing. At first I was thinking it was because all those things ending in "ist" made for awkward consonant clusters. But I'm having a hard time thinking of non-"ist" professions that get the possessive. "Mechanic appointment"... "Veterinary appointment..."

Comment: Perhaps some prefer that, but I say "my eye appointment" and "my optometrist's appointment", "my surgery appt" and "my doctor's appt", etc.

Comment: Just a thought, but the word doctor was a more popular word in use much before most of the other ones. But all appointment-related terms became popular in the same period of time (1980-2000). Perhaps there was some more primitive version of doctor's appointment, but with appointment replaced with another similar word. Or maybe it's because the word "doctor" is more simple, with just two syllables. Other words might be longer and thus it grows out of convention to use 's every time.

Comment: Also note that no one uses "doc's appointment" and the term "doc appointment" is used instead. Makes it even more bizarre.

Comment: How many X's take _X's appointment_, instead of the more common _appointment with X_

Comment: Well, it is the doctor who "grants" *us* an appointment, not us, to him or her. Right?

Comment: I wonder whether it had to do with house calls (the doctor coming to you instead of the other way around). Proper nouns seems to accept the apostrophe-s - "He has Mary's appointment at 10, Mark's appointment at 11 and the doctor's appointment in the afternoon."

Comment: Also lawyer’s appointment, renter’s appointment, contractor’s appointment, etc. The person being referred to is clear in the mind of the speaker, but since the name is probably not meaningful to the listener, the speaker uses the *role* instead.

Comment: Yes. The corresponding << parents' evening >> still seems, according to Google ngrams, to be largely apostrophised (though I'd use the pure attributive form).

Comment: I think this is one of those things that has no rhyme or reason. Idioms like this just happen and spread.

Comment: I found a [source from 1832](https://books.google.com/books?id=mwHvY-h0XCYC&pg=RA1-PA104&dq=%22Doctor%27s+appointment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik2JSA75n1AhWKd98KHc91DSsQuwV6BAgDEAY) that says "dentist appointment" then "doctor's appointment", then "dental appointment". There are definitely older examples but not going back too far — definitely not ME. Even EModE I just didn't see examples of "appointment" being used like this at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is based upon an incorrect use of Ngrams - the form of the query causes Ngrams to display both "occupation" and "occupation's" as the same query.

Comment: I vote to close because the question is based on an assertion that is clearly difficult to substantiate either generally or from this collection of personal experiences.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-it-doctors-appointment-or-doctor-appointment), the apostrophe-s in **doctor's appointment** is not the possessive case, but the genitive case. More specifically, it's a descriptive genitive. The noun **doctor** describes the type of appointment and is used genitively. In **doctor appointment**, the noun is used attributively, as an adjective to describe the appointment.

Their research suggests that, while **doctor's appointment** seems to be more commonly used, it's simply a matter of preference or convention. Both are equally correct.